# get all values of dropdownlist to see if loaded value has changed using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

This is to check if a user is opening another div (form; there are four for the page) without having saved the entry or update for the current form.

I need to compare the current value of dropdowns to all the possible choices of the dropdowns. If there is a difference the user is shown an alert notifying of having not saved the data. There is a not a set number of dropdowns. My script has been able to correctly count the number of dropdowns for each form.

Thanks,

James

Comment: So is the user adding entries to the dropdown, or changing the initial value, or both?

Comment: Just possibly changing the initial value (which is a better way I should have posed the question). The scenario is that the user opens one of the forms (divs), makes a change and for whatever reason does not save it but clicks to another form or page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by updating a variable on change of your select and then checking that value whenever you do what it is you do to move on to the next form.  Here's the code I have mocked up:

HTML -

```
<select id="one">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="two">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="three">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<br />
<!-- The submit buttons -->
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
<br />
<!-- The link that moves on to the next form -->
<a href="#" id="moveOn">Move on</a>
```

Javascript -

```
// the variable
var selectChanged = false;
// set up everything on load
window.onload = function() {

    // bind handlers to submit button, link, an dselects
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = submitForm;
    document.getElementById("moveOn").onclick = moveOn;

    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var numSelects = selects.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numSelects; i++) {
        selects[i].onchange = noteChanged;
    }
}

function submitForm() {
    // set the changed variable to false
    selectChanged = false;
}

function moveOn() {
    // if the select has changed without save, alert the user and prevent
    // link actions
    if (selectChanged) {
        alert("You have changed a form value but not saved it");
        return false;
    }
}

// update the value for each time a select changes
function noteChanged() {
    selectChanged = true;
}
```

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/nYNXY/3/) in action

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

1. Whenever a change happens (you can attach to the onChange event for any form elements you need to track), set a flag somewhere that indicates the form (or whatever) is "dirty". (a good place to put this is in [data- attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/))
2. When the form gets saved, the saving process can re-set the dirty flag to clean
3. Whatever method is used to switch forms can check first to see if the dirty flag is set, and if so, display an error (or warning) and prevent the next form from being shown.

With these 3 pieces in place, you should be able to easily detect a dirty (unsaved) form and take the appropriate actions.